# How does it work SQLiteOpenHelper Context

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, android-context

I have an app with two activities.

One of them list several values while the other add new values to a DB.

I have a class wich extends from SQLiteOpenHelper and manages the DB connections, queries, etc.

Now, I understand that in the constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper you have to pass a context which is used to determine if it has to create a new DB or open an existing one.

But  if I have one instance of the SQLiteOpenHelper  class in each activity, then the context would be different.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass in the Application context, (.getApplication()) instead of the Activity. That way, both instances will access the db using the same context.

Answer (score 2):

The `Context` could be different but not create different DB's. The [SQLiteOpenHelper constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) has a `name` parameter, that's the DB file name. If this exists will not create no matter the `Context` passed.

Comment: Context is an interface for accessing system resources. As mentioned by sabadow, which database is determined by name.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the created database is **associated with the context's application package**. So it doesn't matter whether you have passed the Application context or Activity context.

[**Context.java**](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java)

```
/**
 * Open a new private SQLiteDatabase associated with this Context's
 * application package.  Create the database file if it doesn't exist.
 ...
 ...
 */
public abstract SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name,
        int mode, CursorFactory factory);
```